# I get an undefined [i]

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

in this code, you are suposed to first tell how many people are (number), then their names (in this case Manolo and Juan), then you have to type a "P" or "A", if you press P, this value gets a +1, so the array it's like this => [name, p, a]. Trying to this with "for" gets me an error of an undefined [i], I don't know how this happens

```js
let alumnosNumero = prompt("¿Cuantos hay?");
let alumnosTotal = [];

for (i = 0; i < alumnosNumero; i++) {
  alumnosTotal[i] = [prompt("¿Nombre del alumno " + (i + 1) + "?"), 0, 0];
}

// alumnosTotal = [nombre1, nombre2]
// nombre1 = [juan, 0, 0]
// nombre2 = [Manolo, 0, 0]

// almunosTotales = [[Manolo, 0], [Juan, 0]]

const asistencia = (nombre) => {
  let asistencia = prompt(nombre + " ha estado --> P = presente | A = ausente");
  if (asistencia == "P" || asistencia == "p") {
    alumnosTotal[i][1]++;
  } else if (asistencia == "A" || asistencia == "a") {
    alumnosTotal[i][2];
  }
};

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (alumnos in alumnosTotal) {
    asistencia(alumnosTotal[alumnos][0]);
  }
}

document.write(alumnosTotal);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<style>
  * {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
</style>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="js/pruebas.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which line shows this error?

Comment: `alumnos` is an array and because of that `alumnosTotal[alumnos][0]` doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to do there ?

Comment: The line that shows error is `alumnosTotal[i][1]` and `alumnosTotal[i][2]` that are in the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at array notation in JS, the error was in statements such as asistencia(alumnosTotal[alumnos][0].

If I understood your quesiton correctly this should do

```js
let alumnosNumero;
let days;
let alumnosTotal = [];

readStudentAmmount();
readStudentNames();
readTotalDays();
checkIfAttended();

function readStudentAmmount() {
  alumnosNumero = prompt("¿How Many students?");
}

function readStudentNames() {
  for (i = 0; i < alumnosNumero; i++) {
    alumnosTotal[i] = [prompt("Enter Student Name " + (i + 1) + "?"), 0, 0];
  }
}

function readTotalDays() {
  days = prompt("¿How many days?");
}

function checkIfAttended() {
  alumnosTotal.forEach((alumno)=> {
    for (let i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
      const asistencia = prompt("asistio a clases el dia " + i + "? P = Presente | A = Ausente")
      if (asistencia == "p"){
        alumno[1]++
      } else {
        alumno[2]++
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(alumnosTotal)
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<style>
  * {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
</style>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="js/pruebas.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```